# Node.js app can't access any env variables when pm2 is started from a script but can when launched from ssh

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, pm2

I am trying to launch a node.js app on a production EC2 server with pm2 process manager.

When I ssh into the instance and run `pm2 start app.js`, PM2 starts just fine and has access to all environment variables. Everything good.

However, I want to run `pm2 start app.js` from a Codedeploy hook script called `applicationstart.sh`, the app fails with an `errored` status becasue it is missing all environment variables.
[image]

Here is where the script is added so it is launched with each deployment and calls pm2 start: appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/teller-install
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/afterinstall.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/applicationstart.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

Here is the applicationstart script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running Hook: applicationstart.sh"
cd /home/ubuntu/teller-install/Server/
pm2 start app.js
exit 0
```

I am logged in as ubuntu when I run the script from ssh and I set the script in the appconfig.yml to run as ubuntu as well.

Why would there be any difference between starting pm2 from terminal and starting it from a launch hook script?

Here is running directly from ssh:

[image]

I can provide any information necessary in dire need of solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add `source /etc/profile` before I call pm2 start app.js to load in environment variables.

The script now looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running Hook: applicationstart.sh"
cd /home/ubuntu/teller-install/Server/
source /etc/profile
pm2 start app.js
exit 0
```